# Install `laravel` error `could not find driver`

Tags: laravel-5.8

Install `laravel` error `could not find driver`

问题：
The version of `laravel` is `5.8.38`
The version of `php` is `7.4.3`
The version of `mysql` is `8.0.21`

I get the error `could not find driver` when installing `laravel`

The mysql database has been configured, and the data has been migrated to the mysql database. It should not be reported that the driver cannot be found.

```
{
    "message": "could not find driver (SQL: select * from `my_admin` where `mobile` = 18912345678 order by `id` asc limit 1)",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
    "file": "/home/ubuntu/ygd/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
    "line": 664,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/home/ubuntu/ygd/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
            "line": 624,
            "function": "runQueryCallback",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/ubuntu/ygd/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
            "line": 333,
            "function": "run",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/ubuntu/ygd/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php",
            "line": 2130,
            "function": "select",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
            "type": "->"
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `php -i |grep mysqlnd` to check if the `mysql` driver is enabled, not `php -m`

In addition, about the PHP operating environment, if it is a local development environment

`homestead` is recommended under windows

`valet` is recommended under macOS

The server environment recommends `lnmp` one-click installation package